# How can I use AES to encrypt files other than text files? PDF, Word, etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, aes

I am attempting to encrypt/decrypt files in C# ASP NET 5.0 and I can get it to work for .txt files and regular strings of course. But if I attempt to encrypt a PDF file then decrypt it, it is corrupted and I cannot open it. I am just using EBC right now, I know it isn't secure but I am just trying to test it out before I add in the other options.

```
    public static void encrypt(string fileLocation, string encryptedFileLocation, string key)
        {
            FileStream fp = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            FileStream encryptedFile = new FileStream(encryptedFileLocation, FileMode.Create);

            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("asdfasdfasdfasdf"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("fdsafdsafdsafdsa"));
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedFile, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read;

                try
                {
                    while((read = fp.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }
                } 
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    fp.Close();
                    encryptedFile.Close();
                }

            }
        }

        public static void decrypt(string cypherFileLocation, string decryptedFileLocation, string key)
        {
            FileStream fp = new FileStream(cypherFileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            FileStream decryptedFile = new FileStream(decryptedFileLocation, FileMode.Create);


            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("asdfasdfasdfasdf"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("fdsafdsafdsafdsa"));
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fp, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

                try
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read;
                    while((read = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        decryptedFile.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        decryptedFile.Flush();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    fp.Close();
                    decryptedFile.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your encryption works? You are suppressing any exception, so if there is an error you will never know.

Comment: I end up with two additional files, the encrypted one and the decrypted one. When I use txt files I can open them and the decrypted has the same text as the plain text one.

Just when I do it with a PDF or other files, it opens the reader but then says there is an error and couldn't open the PDF.

Comment: RESOLVED: The try block was surpressing an error when it came to the larger files. The text file was short so it it only executed FlushFinalBlock() once, but with larger files it would execute more than once and it was an error. Thank you :) I am dumb sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment above, there is an error in your code that is not visible because you hide the exceptions with an empty catch block. The exception is a NotSupportedException and the message is

> FlushFinalBlock() method was called twice on a CryptoStream. It can
> only be called once

The encryption works fine with text files that are under 1024 bytes in length but any file (also text files) with a larger size will crash because the code tries to call two or more time the **cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();**

So, I have tested this change to your code and it works

```
try
{
    while ((read = fp.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        cryptoStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    // Moved outside the loop
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
finally
{
    fp.Close();
    encryptedFile.Close();
}
```

In the decryption routine you have as well a call to Flush inside the loop that is not necessary and could be moved outside the loop. But in this case there are no visible errors. In any case, do not hide exceptions, they are essential to understand and fix errors.